# Purpose? appBundle.js in TypeScript Apache Cordova

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

Why does `Visual Studio 2015 RC` compile `TypeScript` in the “scripts” folder in the root of your Cordova project and copy them as a single JavaScript file called `“appBundle.js”` under the `“www/scripts”` folder?

Is this a best practice?
Does this just apply to Visual Studio?
Is this an Apache Cordova approach?

Only documentation I could find about appbundle.js: https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/blob/59cbbb28102f84c1db159c3a4d3d66da659ffff8/tutorial-gulp/gulp-typescript.md

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for using VS 2015 RC!

While building Cordova application, typically you would want all your web assets (including your JavaScript files) in the *www* folder which is then used during the native platform builds.

Visual Studio pre-compiles all your TS files before the actual platform builds(iOS, Windows, Android),  concatenates them and places a single file called "*appBundle.js*" into the *www* folder.

Though its discouraged to change this, you can find this setting at the following location: *C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets*

```
<TypeScriptOutFile>$(ProjectDir)\www\scripts\appBundle.js</TypeScriptOutFile>
```

Comment: Subhag Oak,  Thanks for the response.  I'm trying to figure out the reasoning why `appBundle.js` is being used for Apache Cordova. Especially, since VS `HTML application with TypeScript` creates individual .js from each .ts file and does not compile into a single file. What was the rational for the VS Apache Cordova approach?

Comment: The rationale was to keep down on the number of assets. In Web dev environments, we find developers concatenating their ts files and that's the pattern we adhere to.

Comment: Thanks again for the response.  I was thinking that a `tsconfig.json` would allow more control over `TypeScripts` compiling. Using `tsconfig.json`, I could then set my compiler options as necessary.  In addition, I could use `TSD` to manage my TypeScript definitions. For example, `tsd.json, gulp and gulp-tsd` to manage my typing and create `tsd.d.ts`.  I'm just trying to determine a good workflow.  I like the idea of using NPM, Bower, and Gulp in my workflow as I have complete control.  appBundle.js is great, but I don't think I have control.

Comment: A few problems with using appBundle:  1. We generate this project from a web project - causes each form to have a different .js include list (App & web project).  2. I really like "compile on save" option (which generates a separate .js file) - this would seem to cause a duplicate definition if appBundle.js also contains the same code.  3. In our SPA system, each form load's it's own .js - at least one of these files will have initialization scripts.  When bundle everything into appBundle.js, then initialization logic for every form is always called.  I can't get normal .js generation working.

Comment: Did this change at all with the release of VS 2015? I have a typescript/cordova project that fails to build now that I've upgraded to the release version of VS 2015. It is also compiling typescript files immediately into .js files next to the original .ts file. This is very confusing...

Comment: Just to follow up. With the final version of VS 2015 I found I needed to add a tsconfig.json file to control how Typescript compilation happens. There must have been some sort of default settings that worked well. I also needed to add a tsd.json and use tsd to include my typescript definition files as needed. Using Nuget packages for the definition files wasn't working the same either.